# ObservableCollection not working the RaisePropertyChangeEvent

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I am using MVVM light. Initially I add two items; after that I am adding two more new items in the list, and calling the `RaisePropertyChanged` event; but it's not updating the list view, it's showing old items only. What is the problem in my code?

My Model

```C#
public class ViewPeopleModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _imageURL;
    public string ImageURL
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageURL;
        }
        set
        {
            _imageURL = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageURL");
        }
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```C#
public class ViewPeopleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewPeopleModel> ProfileList { get; set; }

    public ViewPeopleViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ViewPeopleModel> _people = new ObservableCollection<ViewPeopleModel>();
        _people.Add(new ViewPeopleModel { ImageURL = "url1" });
        _people.Add(new ViewPeopleModel { ImageURL = "url2" });

        ProfileList = _people;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ProfileList");
    }
    public void AddNewPeople()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ViewPeopleModel> _people = new ObservableCollection<ViewPeopleModel>();
        _people.Add(new ViewPeopleModel { ImageURL = "url5" });
        _people.Add(new ViewPeopleModel { ImageURL = "url6" });

        ProfileList = _people;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ProfileList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which binding type you are using in XAML ? make sure you are using "TwoWay" or, "OneWay"

Comment: It would be useful to see your xaml too.

Comment: i am using TowWay binding

Comment: Spend five minutes to [edit] your question and fix the terrible formatting.  It will help your questions in future.  Also, your ObservableCollection properties should be read only, and you should be updating the collection, not replacing it.  If you want to just replace the collection, make it an IEnumerable and have the property raise the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your `AddNewPeople` method

```
public void AddNewPeople()
{
       ProfileList.Clear();

       ProfileList.Add(new ViewPeopleModel{ ImageURL ="url5" });
       ProfileList.Add(new ViewPeopleModel{ ImageURL ="url6" });
}
```